# Do third-party USB ethernet adaptors work in Macbook Pro Retinas?

Tags: network, usb, thunderbolt, ethernet, 3rd-party

There seems to be conflicting information on the web, so I wanted to check if there are any problems buying a third party ethernet adaptor (eg [this one](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/USB-2-0-to-RJ45-LAN-Ethernet-Network-Adapter-for-PC-Win7-MacBook-Pro-Air-Mac-OS-/260954653609?pt=AU_Components&hash=item3cc21c03a9&_uhb=1)). This is for a current (mid 2014) 15" rMBP.

I'd just like to save a few dollars ove the Apple Thunderbolt one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As very every electronic devices, there are good ones and there crappy ones.

Apple does not forbid the use of third party USB adapters.

Most of the time if the device does't work, it isn't Apple's fault but the device/driver problem.

So yes they should work.

Answer (score 0):

With my experience, they work.  Make sure to keep instructions so you know where to download the drivers.

Since your MacBook does not have a DVD drive, you will have to get the drivers for the adaptor from the manufacturer.  If you want to avoid this get the Mac thunderbolt adaptor.

Hope this is helpful.  Also if you have usb3 look for a usb3 adapter.

Comment: Thanks. Should have followed up - I got one and it worked fine :)